# Sampling from specific distribution

Tags: sampling, random-variable, simulation, independence

Suppose I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are independent. Also suppose that I can sample from $X+Y$ and $Y$. Is it possible to combine those two sampling algorithms to get samples for $X$.

Answer (score 3):

If you sample from $X+Y$  and $Y$ independently (separately), the answer is no.

For example, suppose $X$ and $Y$ follow the standard normal distribution, then $X+Y$ follows $N(0,2)$. $(X+Y) - Y \sim~ N(0,3)$, instead of expected standard normal distribution. Apart from $(X+Y) - Y$, I cannot find any other way to recreate $X$.

In fact when you sample from $X+Y$  and $Y$ independently, the correlation between  $X+Y$  and $Y$ are lost, so it is impossible to recreate $X$ from $X+Y$  and $Y$.

Comment: The covariance of $Y$ and $X+Y$ is $\text{var}(Y)$, hence they cannot be independent. Ever.